# Connecting PHP to custom DB through the ODBC

Tags: php, database, pdo, odbc, driver

I have university project - create own DBMS with some basic functions like insert, delete, sort, etc. Also I have to connect my DB to the web application which is written on PHP. This PHP frontend works with PDO(php data objects).

It seems like I need a driver(likely ODBC) to connect to my DB. But the problem is that I just don't know how make it work.

Is there any ways to "adapt" my DB to some requirements of driver(ODBC) or there's some another way to make it work?

Comment: try to google "How connect to Database using PHP"

Comment: @Blip Yes, of course I searched this. But there's only information about existing databases like MySql, not your own implemented. So I don't know what to do.